# can't remove properly Fragment from FragmentStatePagerAdapter (ViewPager)

Tags: android, android-fragments

i have a `ViewPager` which extends `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` code:

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
int mNumOfTabs;

private ArrayList<Integer> page_indexes;

public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
    super(fm);
    this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
}
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            TabFragment1 tab1 = new TabFragment1();
            return tab1;
        case 1:
            TabFragment2 tab2 = new TabFragment2();
            return tab2;
        case 2:
            TabFragment3 tab3 = new TabFragment3();
            return tab3;
        case 3:
            TabFragment4 tab4 = new TabFragment4();
            return tab4;
        case 4:
            TabFragment5 tab5 = new TabFragment5();
            return tab5;
        case 5:
            TabFragment6 tab6 = new TabFragment6();
            return tab6;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
    FragmentManager manager = ((Fragment) object).getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction trans = manager.beginTransaction();
    trans.remove((Fragment) object);
    trans.commit();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mNumOfTabs;
}
}
```

in my MainActivity am adding Tabs in my TabLayout

```
    tabLayout.addTab(tab1);
    tabLayout.addTab(tab2);
    tabLayout.addTab(tab3);//post
    tabLayout.addTab(tab4);
    tabLayout.addTab(tab5);//channels
    tabLayout.addTab(tab6);
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
```

and this is how am removing tabs

```
tabLayout.removeTab(tab3)
tabLayout.removeTab(tab5)
```

well its working fine on some points ,  cause now i have only 4 tabs in my Activity but the problem is that when i select the tab4 which is after tab2 since i removed tab3 it still shows the tab3. so it means only the last 2 tabs are removed not the specified  ones.

i know am missing something but dont know what, well i tried to google it and gone through some documentations of tab layout , fragments even checked some StackOverflow threads about removing tabs from ViewPager but the approaches was not clear enough for me so if anybody can me give some guidance and help me with this then it'll be so good for me

Comment: I think part of your problem is that your getCount() method always returns a fixed size. Instead of having 5 tab fragments, just put them into an ArrayList.

Comment: you mean i should not use the switch case and replace it with an array of fragments and loop through it ?

Comment: Well you don't loop through it. You find an fragment you want to delete by using the position paramater and applying it to the ArrayList. Like ArrayList.remove(position)

Comment: oh okay , you know any tutorial where i can learn it ? am a noob in android man

Comment: I think this may help. https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html